# Javascript - Getting null when I expect number

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have some Javascript that hashes.  msgBuffer definitely has bytes in it after the hash, but in the following code, the nonce ends up null.  What do I need to do to add the first byte of msgBuffer to the nonce?

```
    var msgBuffer = await crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-256', toHash); //returns ArrayBuffer
    var nonce = 0;
    nonce += msgBuffer[0]; // results in null
```

Comment: the msgBuffer returns ArrayBuffer.
See example here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/digest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`await crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-256', toHash)` would return ArrayBuffer.

You should first convert it to proper type, and then get the value.

e.g. do this.

```
var msgBuffer = await crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-256', toHash);
var myArr = new Uint8Array(msgBuffer);
var nonce = 0;
nonce += myArr[0];
```

I used `Uint8Array`, here because for [crypto.subtle.digest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/digest#converting_a_digest_to_a_hex_string) this seems an appropriate choice, but for other use cases and types you expect in an ArrayBuffer in general, you should use the [type array views](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays#typed_array_views).

Comment: Excellent.  I was making the assumption that msgBuffer was already a Uint8Array.  Thank you.

Comment: Added tip: if you don't want to transform the entire array each time, I did this: var myArr = new Uint8Array(msgBuffer.slice(0,5));